# How can I shorten my Tkinter textbox code to avoid repetition?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-text

I'm writing a custom textbox to save my customer data to my database. I use Tkinter in python to create the UI, there are 5 textbox, each for different purpose. This is the code I use to create the textbox:

```
windows_a = Frame(root)
windows_a.pack(side=RIGHT, anchor=NE, padx=5, pady=30)
windows_a = Text(windows_a, width=16, height=38, font=("Consolas Bold", 11),
                 undo=True, tabs=25, insertbackground="white",
                 selectbackground="gray", selectforeground="yellow",
                 background="black", foreground="lime", wrap="none")
windows_a.pack()
windows_b = Frame(root)
windows_b.pack(side=RIGHT, anchor=NE, padx=0, pady=30)
windows_b = Text(windows_b, width=16, height=38, font=("Consolas Bold", 11),
                 undo=True, tabs=25, insertbackground="white",
                 selectbackground="gray", selectforeground="yellow",
                 background="black", foreground="lime", wrap="none")
windows_b.pack()
windows_c = Frame(root)
windows_c.pack(side=RIGHT, anchor=NE, padx=5, pady=30)
windows_c = Text(windows_c, width=30, height=38, font=("Consolas Bold", 11),
                 undo=True, tabs=25, insertbackground="white",
                 selectbackground="gray", selectforeground="yellow",
                 background="black", foreground="lime", wrap="none")
windows_c.pack()
username, password = Frame(root), Frame(root)
username.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW, padx=5, pady=5)
username.place(x=5, y=35)
username = Text(username, width=10, height=1, font=("Consolas Bold", 11),
                undo=True, tabs=25, insertbackground="white",
                selectbackground="gray", selectforeground="yellow",
                background="black", foreground="lime")
username.pack()
password.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW, padx=5, pady=0)
password.place(x=5, y=62)
password = Text(password, width=10, height=1, font=("Consolas Bold", 11),
                undo=True, tabs=25, insertbackground="white",
                selectbackground="gray", selectforeground="yellow",
                background="black", foreground="lime")
password.pack()
```

As you can see, apart from the position and size, the code is the same so I want to shorten it to make the code less repetitive. I tried to use grid but the different in their position and size make grid not a viable option.

Is there a way I can achieve the same output with less code, that isn't so repetitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on Henry's answer above: You can use loops to dynamically create `CustomText` objects.

```
windows_a, windows_b, windows_c = Frame(root), Frame(root), Frame(root)
widths = [16, 16, 30]
i = 0

for window in [windows_a, windows_b, windows_c]:
    window.pack(side=RIGHT, anchor=NE, padx=5, pady=30)
    CustomText(window, width = widths[i], height = 38).pack()
    i+= 1

username, password = Frame(root), Frame(root)

yi = 35

for frame in [username, password]:
    frame.place(x=5, y=yi)
    CustomText(frame, width=10, height=1).pack()
    yi = 64 # or yi += 29 if there eventually becomes more than two objects to loop through.
```

Comment: uhm I just followed up on Henry's' idea. No need to mark mine as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap `Text` in your own class with default keyword arguments (kwargs). Then you can create instances of it like you did with `Text` but only specifying the arguments that change.

If you were to specify a different background colour, for example, this would override the defaults. If you want the default to always be enforced, change `default_kwargs.update(kwargs)` to `kwargs.update(default_kwargs)` and `Text.__init__(self, *args, **default_kwargs)` to `Text.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)`.

```
class CustomText(Text):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        default_kwargs = {
            "font": ("Consolas Bold", 11),
            "undo": True,
            "tabs": 25,
            "insertbackground": "white",
            "selectbackground": "gray",
            "selectforeground": "yellow",
            "background": "black",
            "foreground": "lime",
            "wrap": "none"
        }
        default_kwargs.update(kwargs)
        Text.__init__(self, *args, **default_kwargs)

windows_a = Frame(root)
windows_a.pack(side=RIGHT, anchor=NE, padx=5, pady=30)
windows_a = CustomText(windows_a, width=16, height=38)
windows_a.pack()
windows_b = Frame(root)
windows_b.pack(side=RIGHT, anchor=NE, padx=0, pady=30)
windows_b = CustomText(windows_b, width=16, height=38)
windows_b.pack()
windows_c = Frame(root)
windows_c.pack(side=RIGHT, anchor=NE, padx=5, pady=30)
windows_c = CustomText(windows_c, width=30, height=38)
windows_c.pack()
username, password = Frame(root), Frame(root)
username.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW, padx=5, pady=5)
username.place(x=5, y=35)
username = CustomText(username, width=10, height=1)
username.pack()
password.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW, padx=5, pady=0)
password.place(x=5, y=62)
password = CustomText(password, width=10, height=1)
password.pack()
```

Comment: Even better: you can use loops to create the Frames and CustomTexts.